# How do you split video files into smaller chunks in the browser?

Tags: javascript

I am following the documentation for [api.video](https://docs.api.video/5.1/videos-and-streaming/upload-large-tutorial#step-3-splitting-the-video) and they say you can "upload videos over 128MB, it just needs to be split into separate chunks (under 128 MB), and each chunk uploaded separately."

This is what I have so far - it doesn't split the videoFile (from a file type input), so it only works for small video files.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', videoFile);
fetch(`https://sandbox.api.video/videos/${videoId}/source`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
  body: formData,
});
```

Comment: Maybe use chunck_split() cuz I'm guessing that you are sending video in base64 format. Docs - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php

Comment: Ah shit wait to much php. Here found equivalent in js https://gist.github.com/mvpoorna/1d6c3e37cb456f9fa147399a49261bbb

Comment: Look at something like https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Chunked-file-uploads for inspiration. You need to split the blobs.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob. This is pretty complicated to handle correctly and is probably too much for a stack overflow answer

Comment: @mortimer OP is asking about client side chunking

Comment: Recommended closing since this does not show an actual attempt at chunking. See links I posted, try something and ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the video into different chunks in different ways.

For example:

Split your video into chunks, if you're on a mac you can use this command:

`$ split -b 100m source.mp4.mp4 file_chunk_`

Split your video into chunks, if you're using Linux you can use this command:

`$ /path/to/source.mp4` is a 289MB (`281905832 B`) file .`

However, all the client libraries of api.video are now able to split the videos for you if you upload videos that are larger than 200 MiB. See reference here: https://docs.api.video/docs/upload-a-video-regular-upload#create-a-video-container-and-upload-a-video-over-200-mb-with-a-progressive-upload